# Проблема с @import в SCSS

Tags: веб-программирование, вёрстка

Столкнулся с **бедой.**
А именно не работает @import в SCSS

```
@import '_reset';
@import 'variables';
@import 'fonts';
...
@import 'media';
```

Название файлов _variables.scss и т.д. ( _reset.css файл ).
Собираю простеньким gulp таском:

```
gulp.task('scss', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/scss/main.scss')
        .pipe(gulpSass())
        .pipe(gulpAutoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], {cascade:true}))
        .pipe(gulpConcat("style.css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
});
```

В файле style.css (после сборки) всё как и должно было быть, но при попытке изменить, к примеру, _fonts.scss, gulp падает и выдает:

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: src\scss\main.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: fonts.
       Parent style sheet: C:/Users/vdodovych/Documents/WEB programming/Template/src/scss/main.scss
        on line 3 of src/scss/main.scss
>> @import 'fonts';
   ^

    at options.error (C:\Users\vdodovych\Documents\WEB programming\Template\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:291:26)
```

Не могу понять, что я делаю не так.
* Читал про @import, решение проблемы не нашел, возможно не там\не то читал.
**P.S. Прошу строго не судить, я пока еще только учусь :)**
**P.S. Приношу извинения за мой ужасный русский, прошу простить, он не родной :)**

Answer (score 1):

Итак, методом танцев с бубном, aки шаман, было определенно:
Код из примера выше работает в WebStorm что навело на мысль, что проблема в моей **IDE**.
Начал копать в ту сторону, и нашел решение: в моем случае **(Sublime Text 3)** достаточно добавить `"atomic_save": true` в настройки.
Понятия не имею каким образом, но проблема **решена.**